# SyntaxError app_name while using Django

Tags: python, django, syntax-error

Hi everyone I edited this post and still got an error can someone please help.

The error is:

```
  File "C:\Users\myshop\myshop\urls.py", line 25, in <module>
    url(r'^', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
  File "C:\Users\Faruq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 39, in include
    'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
```

and the urls.py is this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name='shop'

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                                document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: You are missing a close bracket/paren on the previous line. Voting to close this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a trivial problem that OP could have solved.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48507481/edit) to include more information.  The close vote for typos is normal for the site --- don't be discouraged.  Good luck!

Comment: well, the error message tells you what to do: provide an appname *in the included* module, not in this one (you have an app named shop and added it to INSTALLED_APPS, right?)

Answer (score 1):

```
url(r'^', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop'),
```

You're missing a close bracket on this line.

Third party libraries can't cause `SyntaxError`s in your code.

EDIT:  You put the bracket in the wrong place.  Refer to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names).

`url(path, view_or_include, namespace=string)`

You need to have `url(r'^', include('shop.urls'), namespace='shop'),`

Please don't edit the question to be completely different after it's been answered.  :(

Comment: Happens to all of us.

Comment: Updated @MadeinLondon

Answer (score 0):

from this to:

```
url(r'^', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop'),
```

change to this:

```
url(r'^', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
```

Comment: thanks I corrected it but still getting syntax issues. I edited the post to explain.